# URLError(_nsError: The operation could not be completed) error when trying to start dataTask

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, vapor, urlsession

I've got a Vapor server app (hosted on Heroku), that connects to an external API service through a URLSession dataTask.

So far it has been working perfectly (and still works fine when ran locally on my Mac), but since last server restart the dataTask throws the following error every time: `URLError(_nsError: The operation could not be completed)`.

I've heard Swift on Linux had problems with URLSession in the past, but they were mostly resolved. Does anyone have any solution for this? Thank you!

Code:

```
func foo(task: RepeatedTask) {

        // get request to ZTM API
        guard let client = try? app.client() else {
            return
        }
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: Globals.API_URL)!
        urlComponents.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "resource_id", value: Globals.RESOURCE_ID),
            URLQueryItem(name: "apikey", value: Globals.API_KEY),
            URLQueryItem(name: "type", value: "1")]
        let url = urlComponents.url
        let response = client.get(url!)


        let tempModel = response.flatMap(to: Model.self) { response -> EventLoopFuture<Model> in
            return try response.content.decode(Model.self)
            }.map(to: Model.self) { tempModel -> Model in
                tempModel.busArray.forEach {
                    $0.vehicleID = $0.Lines! + $0.Brigade!
                    $0.angle = 0
                }
                if Globals.myModel.busArray.isEmpty {
                    Globals.myModel.busArray = tempModel.busArray
                } else {
                    // add & remove buses
                    Globals.myModel.busArray.updateVehicleArray(using: tempModel.busArray)

                    // update coordinates + angle
                    Globals.myModel.busArray.updateCoordinates(using: tempModel.busArray)
                }
                return tempModel
        }
}
```

The url produced from `urlComponents` is `https://api.um.warszawa.pl/api/action/busestrams_get/?resource_id=f2e5503e-927d-4ad3-9500-4ab9e55deb59&apikey=a86c68be-0117-4a88-838c-bcc2f6ba85f4&type=1`

Comment: Mind sharing your code? Also curious why you're opting to use URLSession instead of vapor's http client https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/http/client/

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://github.com/vzsg/CurlyClient

Comment: @TWOF I've added code to my question. I tried using the Client as you can see in the code, but it didn't help. Still works perfectly on my Mac though...